# How to run a asp.net controller method at certain time once a day

Tags: asp.net, angular, server, controller, delay

My asp.net web project has a controller method "CalByNowBalance" that needs to run periodically, saying once a day at 7am.
Referring to a [blog](https://hrnjica.net/2014/01/30/how-to-run-the-code-daily-at-specific-time-in-c/), I created a trimTrigger() within my project controller class. I have no idea how to get it run at 7am every day. Should this trigger method be place in a separate class other than being included in the controller? If this should be triggered as a windows server, how? I use Angular for client, can it be manipulated from client side? Any solution or advice would be greatly appreciated.

```html
public async Task<ActionResult> TimeTrigger() {
            //Time when method needs to be called
            var DailyTime = "07:00:00";
            var timeParts = DailyTime.Split(new char[1] {':'});

            while(true)
            {
                var dateNow = DateTime.Now;
                var date = new DateTime(dateNow.Year, dateNow.Month, dateNow.Day,
                    int.Parse(timeParts[0]), int.Parse(timeParts[1]), int.Parse(timeParts[2]));
                TimeSpan timeSpan;

                if (date > dateNow) timeSpan = date - dateNow;
                else
                {
                    date = date.AddDays(1);
                    timeSpan = date - dateNow;
                };

                //waits certan time and run the code
                Task.Delay(timeSpan).Wait();
                
                await CalByNowBalance();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have access to Azure account you can make one [Azure function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-scheduled-function) with time trigger.
In this function you can post to a Web Api that will be created in your ASP.Net project. From this Web Api you can then call your controller class.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).